# Node.js - Emit an event from another function/object

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter, emit

I'm struggling with this for almost 2hours and still not getting it.=( For explanation I got the following code.

```
var util = require('util');
var events = require('events').EventEmitter;

function a (){
    //this is my first function
    var b_obj = new b();
    b_obj.on('event',function(){
        console.log('Something happened!');
    });
};

function b (){
    //this is my second function
    events.call(this);
    this.emit('event');
};

util.inherits(b, events);
a();
```

So what I try to do is: I got a function called "a". This function calls a second function called  "b". This function validates some data and emits events depending on the result of the validation.

What I found out is, that the listener works fine and the event is correct emitted. But, as it looks like the event is emitted in the context of function b and the listener works in the context of function a. For further investigations I added the following line to function b:

```
this.on('event', function(){
        console.log('event emitted!');
    });
```

And this works. Can anybody help me? I'm sure the solution is pretty simple. =(

Comment: Yes, the event is triggered *on* the `obj_b` instance, and that's the context for all listeners.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @Bergi: The problem isn’t the value of `this`, but the relative timing of the `emit` and `on` calls, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @icktoofay: I must have misunderstood the term "context", yes. I already wondered how "*the listener works fine and the event is correct*" though `emit` is synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you mean is inform the function a() when the validation process in function b() is complete, then just emit the event from b after doing the validation.
I use setTimeout() for asyncronous example.

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var theEvent = new EventEmitter();

function a(){
  console.log('preparing validation..');
  theEvent.on('validationDone', function(validationResult){
    console.log('validation result is ' + validationResult);  // prints 'validation result is true' in the next 2 sec
  });
  b();
}

function b(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var result = true;
    theEvent.emit('validationDone', result);
  }, 2000);
}

a();
```

Comment: In Node.js, you’d probably use `process.nextTick`.

Comment: of course in practical use-case we should use process.nextTick instead of setTImeout 0ms. I just using it as the example that theEvent will emit event in the next 2 sec.

Answer (score -1):

The event handler function is always called in the context of the object that emits the event, in this case `b`. In your example you could simply do

```
function a() {
  var self = this;

  ...
}
```

to remember `a`'s context, but I assume your real code is different and you may not have your event handler specified as a closure, so you can instead bind your handler to the desired object before setting it:

```
function a (){
    //this is my first function
    var b_obj = new b();
    b_obj.on('event', handlerFunction.bind(this));
}
```

In this case, your `handlerFunction` will always be called in the context of `a`. The `bind` method returns a new function that is bound to the object you provided, see [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

PS. You may want to phrase your questions clearer and provide better examples before you post in the future.

Comment: Hi Antony, thanks for your reply. But I don't get it. Adding 'var self = this;' didn't change anything. In addition I tried it with '.bind(this)'. It's still not working. If you tell me what is unclear I'll try to explain in more detail.

Comment: The problem is the timing, not the value of `this`.

Comment: The real problem is poorly asked question, I too noticed that event is emitted before the listener is setup, but assumed that the question is really about context / `this` value.